# How to get selected text in Word 2011 within Applescript

Tags: applescript

I want to get the selected text in the active document in Word 2011 from Apple-Script.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried this, and it works

```
    tell application "Microsoft Word"
        activate
        try
            set selectedText to content of text object of selection
            display dialog selectedText buttons {"OK"}
        on error
            display dialog "erreur" buttons {"OK"}
        end try
    end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
tell application "Microsoft Word" to get selection's content
```

Comment: But, where can i find the content? in which variable?

Comment: tell application "Microsoft Word" ¬
 set selText to get selection's content¬
end tell

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Word from Office 2021 returns a single character, the one next to the cursor, when nothing is selected. This seems to be a bug in Word's implementation of "get selection's content" or "get content of text object of selection". It seems following code can fix this issue:

```
            tell application "Microsoft Word"
                set theSelection to get selection's content as string
                tell window 1
                    tell pane 1
                        set theSelection to get selection
                        set ixBeg to selection start of theSelection
                        set ixEnd to selection end of theSelection
                    end tell
                end tell
                if ixBeg = ixEnd then
                    set theSelection to "" -- get selection's content returns character after cursor if nothing selected
                end if
            end tell
```